# How do you use external libraries in an Aptana Studio Ruble?

Tags: ruby, aptana

I am trying to create a Ruble for use in my current project, but I need to use an external library. A Rails console can see that library fine, as can a running ruby process.  Yet I get this error from the Ruble

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- kode
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038)
at #<Class:0x10149fee8>.(root)(/home/nekosune/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/RubyIndentor/commands/commands.rb:2)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either Ruby or Ruble but my first guess from the exception message is that you require a missing Ruby Kernel file.  Or you are missing a reference to it.

Comment: errr thankyou, but thats not the problem at all. it can't find a different file, that can be found normally.